# Trying to Convert VB.Net to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm having a problem converting vb.net code I found on the web to C#.

vb.net

```vb
 Protected Overridable Sub OnRowClicked(ByVal e As GridViewRowClickedEventArgs)
    'raise the RowClicked event
    RaiseEvent RowClicked(Me, e)
End Sub

'setup our EventHandler for RowClicked
Public Custom Event RowClicked As EventHandler(Of GridViewRowClickedEventArgs)
    AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler(Of GridViewRowClickedEventArgs))
        Events.AddHandler(RowClickedEventKey, value)
    End AddHandler

    RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler(Of GridViewRowClickedEventArgs))
        Events.RemoveHandler(RowClickedEventKey, value)
    End RemoveHandler

    RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowClickedEventArgs)
        Dim ev As EventHandler(Of GridViewRowClickedEventArgs) = TryCast(Events(RowClickedEventKey), EventHandler(Of GridViewRowClickedEventArgs))
        If Not IsNothing(ev) Then
            ev(sender, e)
        End If
    End RaiseEvent
End Event
```

c#

```
protected virtual void OnRowClicked(GridViewRowClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        //raise the RowClicked event
        if (RowClicked != null)
        {
            RowClicked(this, e);
        }
    }

    //setup our EventHandler for RowClicked
    public event EventHandler<GridViewRowClickedEventArgs> RowClicked
    {
        add { Events.AddHandler(RowClickedEventKey, value); }

        remove { Events.RemoveHandler(RowClickedEventKey, value); }

    }
```

I used a code converter on the web. The problem is on line

```
//raise the RowClicked event
    if (RowClicked != null)
    {
        RowClicked(this, e);
    }
```

The error I'm getting is: The event 'RowClickGridView.RowClicked' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

just remove the add/remove - parts:

```
public event EventHandler<GridViewRowClickedEventArgs> RowClicked;
```

Comment: Not following?  But I need that event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see anthing special here.  Id just use the standard event constructs and forget this custom stuff.

Comment: The standard event handler wire-up syntax in C# is `Object.Event += EventHandlerFunction;`

Answer (score 0):

```
protected virtual void OnRowClicked(GridViewRowClickedEventArgs e)
{
   EventHandler<GridViewRowClickedEventArgs> temp = RowClicked ;
    //raise the RowClicked event
    if (temp != null)
    {
        temp(this, e);
    }
}


public event EventHandler<GridViewRowClickedEventArgs> RowClicked;
```

cf http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx

Comment: I just tried this and I get the same error message on this line " EventHandler<GridViewRowClickedEventArgs> temp = RowClicked ;"

Comment: I don't believe... did you declare the event as I described and remove the add and remove lines?  You don't need those in the templated version they are baked in.

Comment: I'm extending the GridView control in asp.net, i added public event EventHandler<GridViewRowClickedEventArgs> RowClicked;" and it says its already declared. Hmm

Comment: AH HA!  You can't make a custom event with the same name as one already defined.  We've found your problem.

Comment: So what should I do? Rename RowClicked event to something else?  I tried that and I still get that same issue.   But if I remove that event and  just add the declaration "
public event EventHandler<GridViewRowClickedEventArgs> RowClicked;" I don't get any error messages.

Comment: What you should do depends entirely on what you are trying to do.  If you need an event that fires when the row is clicked, just use the existing one and don't write a new one.  If you need something else, first define what it is and then maybe someone can help you on SO -- OR as is often the case, once you know what you are doing the solution will be clear.